# Create separate tables based on values in one column of a base table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My XML was:

```
set @xml=N'
<root>
   <attribute col1="attr1" col2="varchar(200)" col3="A"/>
   <attribute col1="attr2" col2="varchar(200)" col3="A"/>
   <attribute col1="attr3" col2="varchar(200)" col3="B"/>
   <attribute col1="attr4" col2="varchar(200)" col3="C"/>
</root>'
```

I converted the XML into `Base` table in SQL Server:

```
COL1       COL2         COL3
-----------------------------
attr1   varchar(200)    A
attr2   varchar(200)    A
attr3   varchar(200)    B
attr4   varchar(200)    C
```

I want to create tables like

```
create table A
(
    attr1   varchar(200),
    attr2   varchar(200)    
)
```

and similarly for B and C in COL3

Comment: What database are you using?  You need to use dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: Um, why on earth would you be doing this?

Comment: HI, I am using SQL. I am finding it difficult how to partition my tables based on COL3 values and then make seperate tables. A small hint would suffice me. I know i have to apply dynamic sql here. But before that i need to seperate things i guess.

Comment: @sgeddes-  i had to parse xml in sql and put that in my base table (#temp). Now i want to create tables based on my values in col3

Comment: Which database? For sure your are using SQL.

Comment: **DON'T DO THIS!** Keeping this stuff in the same table is almost always the more "correct" schema design. If you're concerned about performance, make sure COL3 the first column in your primary key, and you'll be able to get similar performance as you would with separate tables. Even if the table turns out to be _huge_ (and I'm talking billions of rows), you can use partitioning to get the same performance level that you would from separate tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert values into a new table based on a select query.

```
CREATE TABLE A
  AS (SELECT COL1, COL2
      FROM old_table
      WHERE COL3 = "A");
```

But you will have to do this for every distinct value of `COL3`.

Comment: I believe the OP wants to dynamically create tables based on the xml being imported (type specific).  This will not accomplish that (and won't work in some databases).

Comment: @Daniel- I cant check the value of COL3 as i have made this base table with 3 columns from xml file. so my COL3 can have any values. I want to create new tables based on my values in COL3.

Comment: Then I guess you will not get far with pure SQL and it depends what flavor you're using. In Postgres you should be able to create a function or stored procedure in which you first select all `COL3` values and then loop through them and create the tables accordingly. But looking at your question again, I think @sgeddes is right and my solution wouldn't do what you exactly wanted. Anyway, you need to script this somehow, either in an external script in language of your choice or in something like a custom SQL function/stored procedure.

Comment: @DanielSchroeder - Can you give a little light how to loop and check . i know about stored procedures in sql

Comment: @user3228318 -- if you really want an answer, please answer the question several have already asked -- which database are you using?  mysql?  sql server?  oracle?  other???

Comment: Right. :) And for loops in Postgres e.g. you can read here in the docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING

Comment: @Daniel - there must b some easy way of handling in sql... :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use python to do it,

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json

# Function to remove XML namespaces from the XML content
def remove_xml_namespaces(xml_content):
    return ''.join(['<{}>'.format(tag.split('}')[1]) if '}' in tag else tag for tag in xml_content.split('<')])

# Read the mapping file
mapping_df = pd.read_csv('mapping.csv')

# Read the JSON data from a file
with open('input2.json', 'r') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

# Initialize an empty list to store the data
data = []

for item in json_data:
    # Parse the XML string from the JSON data
    xml_string = item['xmlcol']
    
    # Remove XML namespaces
    xml_string = remove_xml_namespaces(xml_string)

    root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

    # Iterate through root elements in the XML
    for element in root:
        # Initialize a dictionary to store the data for this XML
        xml_data = {}

        # Add "_id" value to the dictionary
        xml_data["_id"] = item["_id"]["$oid"]

        # Iterate through the mapping DataFrame
        for index, row in mapping_df.iterrows():
            xml_path = row['xml_path']
            column_name = row['column_name']

            # Find the element in the current root using the path
            elements = element.findall(xml_path)

            # Extract the values and append to the dictionary
            values = [element.text if element is not None else '' for element in elements]
            xml_data[column_name] = values

        data.append(xml_data)

# Create a DataFrame from the extracted data
result_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Iterate through columns containing arrays and apply explode
for column_name in result_df.columns:
    if isinstance(result_df[column_name].iloc[0], list):
        result_df = result_df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[column_name]), axis=1)
        result_df.rename(columns=lambda col: column_name + str(col), inplace=True)

# Reset the DataFrame index
result_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Replace empty strings with None
result_df = result_df.applymap(lambda x: None if x == '' else x)

# Show the resulting DataFrame
print(result_df)
```

mapping contains the map of which column you want to extract